# Multithreading in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am completely new to Spring. Trying to call a method on a separate thread using Spring Async annotation. This is the code I have tried after looking around a bit:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void asyncMethodWithVoidReturnType() {
        System.out.println("Hello from sout! Execute method asynchronously. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        LOGGER.info("Hello from logger! Execute method asynchronously. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

and the runner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringTestRunner {

    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

When running the main class, I do not see any output from the thread. Why is that?
As you can tell, this is a very basic question, so please explain as much as you can.

Comment: How do you call `asyncMethodWithVoidReturnType`, or do you expect to be automatically called on startup?

Comment: So, you are expecting the MyClass.asyncMethodWithVoidReturnType method to execute automatically when you run your app?

Comment: @cdalxndr @gtiwari333 I thought the `SpringApplication.run(SpringTestRunner.class, args);` line runs the app and then looks what what's async annotated and then calls it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see output because you don't call your asyncMethodWithVoidReturnType function. Example with scheduler:

Writer:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class AsyncWriter {
    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @SneakyThrows
    public void asyncWrite() {
        log.info("Hello! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Scheduler:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Scheduler {

    private final AsyncWriter asyncWriter;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void scheduledWrite() {
        log.info("Scheduler");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            asyncWriter.asyncWrite();
        }
    }
}
```

Runner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringTestRunner {

    @Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        return executor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use the scheduler? Can you add that to the answer as well?

Comment: @Goh-shans You can call asyncWrite() in every `@Component` you want, for example, in `@Service` or `@Controller`. Inject AsyncWriter into your component like I did it in Scheduler and call the method.